# Manually setting a UIButton state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I `UIButton` using + `buttonWithType:`

What I need to figure out is how to manually change the button state. There are times when I need it to be set to "disabled."

I read through the `UIButton` documentation but I cannot seem to find anything about manually setting a button state.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To supplement what Ben said, check out the enabled property in UIControl: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIControl/enabled

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Did you try `button.enabled = NO;`?

**Swift 5.0**

```
button.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: i wonder why button.isEnabled is not writable while button.enabled works

Comment: if (![button isEnabled]) {
               button.enabled = YES;
            } works for me.

Answer (score 28):

there are also the states:

```
   button.highlighted = NO;
   button.selected = NO;
```

Answer (score 4):

Objective C:

```
button.selected = Yes;
button.highlighted = NO;
button.enabled = Yes;
```

Swift 4:

```
button.isSelected = true 
button.isEnabled = true
```

Also you can use:(swift 4)

```
 if (button.state == .selected) {
   //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can manually set state of UIButton.

```
UIButton *btnCheck=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

if(btncheck isselected])
{
    btncheck.selected=FALSE;
}
else
{
    btncheck.selected=TRUE;
}
```

You can do operation on UIButton as per your requirement like perform some action when UIButton is selected and while not selected.

Hope this will help you....

Answer (score 2):

for Swift 3 you can use

button.isSelected = true

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving here looking to change the 'state' of the button (as opposed to 'enabled').  Stephen is correct "This attribute is read only—there is no corresponding setter method."

What you really want to set is the state of the buttons cell.

```
[[myNSButtonOutlet cell] setState: NSOnState];  //Options NSOnState, NSOffState, NSMixedState
```

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate the needs of setting a different button look when it's selected, set `isSelected = true`.

Here is an example of setting the state, and changing the `UIButton` appearance based on that state, using a quiz game environment:

```
if sender.titleLabel?.text == correctAnswer {
    sender.isSelected = true
    // Set title color and image based on 'selected' state.
    sender.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .selected)
    sender.setImage(Utilities.sharedInstance.returnAnswerButtonImage(for: .correctlyAnswered).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .selected)
    sender.backgroundColor = .white
    sender.tintColor = .systemBlue
    // moveToNextQuestion()
} else {
    sender.isSelected = true
    sender.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .selected)
    sender.setImage(Utilities.sharedInstance.returnAnswerButtonImage(for: .incorrectlyAnswered).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .selected)
    sender.backgroundColor = .red
    sender.tintColor = .systemBlue
}
```